# Ignore all git projects under a directory for projectile

Tags: projectile

I am trying out [exercism.io](http://exercism.io/) and whenever I fetch any problem and build, it gets added to `projectile-known-projects` and now I've  a whole bunch of projects under `projectile-known-projects` which I do not want.

So, is there a way to ignore all the *git* projects under a directory, in my case `~/exercism/` directory.

I tried adding `~/exercism/` to `projectile-ignored-projects` but that did not work(looks like it expects **only** the path to an actual project directory not a non-project directory which *contains* projects inside it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize `projectile-ignored-project-function` to specify a custom function that gets called when projectile is about to add a project to the known projects list.

For example, here is a how you might tell projectile to ignore any projects under `foo`. (This uses the `f` library for convenience. If you don't want to install another package you can use string functions or some other mechanism to decide if the given project root should be ignored.)

```
(with-eval-after-load 'projectile
  (require 'f)
  (defun my-projectile-ignore-project (project-root)
    (f-descendant-of? project-root (expand-file-name "/foo")))
  (setq projectile-ignored-project-function #'my-projectile-ignore-project))
```

If you only want to ignore git projects you can add additional checks to the `my-projectile-ignore-project` function, such as checking for a .git subdirectory: `(and ... (file-exists-p (expand-file-name ".git" project-root)))`